# How do I get my public IPV6 address from inside my Java Application?

Tags: java, networking, ip-address, ipv6, ipv4

Normally when I want my public IP from inside my program, I copy-and-paste in this code:

```
    URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(in);
    final String ip = in.readLine(); //you get the IP as a String
    System.out.println("You IP is: " + ip);
```

But that code only gives me my public IPV4 address, and if I type "what is my ip" into Google search, I get a different, IPV6 address instead of the IPV4 one. From inside my application, I want to get the IPV6 address, but I would consider it wasteful to parse the entire Google webpage at "https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what+is+my+ip+" just to find my IPV6 address in it. Does anyone have a better solution that the one I plan on using?

Also, when I try using "https://wtfismyip.com/text" in place of "http://checkip.amazonaws.com", I get a security exception [caused by the leading "https"]

Changing the https to http fixes the security exception, but the updated code still does not work correctly:

```
    {
        final URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                whatismyip.openStream()));
        final String ip = in.readLine(); //you get the IP as a String
       System.out.println("Your IPV4 IP is: " + ip);
    }
    {

        final URL whatismyip2 = new URL("http://wtfismyip.com/text");
        final BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                whatismyip2.openStream()));
        final String ip2 = in2.readLine(); //you get the IP as a String
        Application.printerr("Your IPV6 IP is: " + ip2); // Your IPV6 IP is the same at your IPV4 (wrong because when I check in the web browser is different)
    }
```

In addition, trying to pull the IPV6 address from the Google search "what is my ip" - "https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what+is+my+ip+" - doesn't even give me an ip address at all, neither ipv4 or ipv6. All I get is this:

```
<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content=
"Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features 
to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots">
<meta content="/images/google_favicon_128.png" itemprop="image"><title>Google</title><script>(function(){window.google={kEI:'SAxgVa73L4_FgwSy34LgCw',kEXPI:'3700256,3700366,4017578,4026111,4029815,4031300,4032032,4032500,4032521,
4032631,4032643,4032645,4032677,4032926,4033142,4033184,4033191,4033307,4033344,4034425,4035816,4035881,4035980,
4036005,4036345,4036464,4036486,4036531,4036539,4036665,4036896,4037457,4037538,4037611,8300096,8500394,8500851,
8501248,8501279,8501295,8501351,8501406,8501489,8501497,10200083,10201180,10201191',authuser:0,kSID:'c9c918f0_10'};
google.kHL='en';})();(function(){google.lc=[];google.li=0;google.getEI=function(a){for(var b;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("eid")));)
a=a.parentNode;return b||google.kEI};google.getLEI=function(a){for(var b=null;a&&(!a.getAttribute||!(b=a.getAttribute("leid")));)a=
a.parentNode;return b};google.https=function(){return"https:"==window.location.protocol};google.ml=function(){};google.time=
function(){return(new Date).getTime()};google.log=function(a,b,e,f,l){var d=new Image,h=google.lc,g=google.li,c="",m=
google.ls||"";d.onerror=d.onload=d.onabort=function(){delete h[g]};h[g]=d;if(!e&&-1==b.search("&ei=")){
var k=google.getEI(f),c="&ei="+k;-1==b.search("&lei=")&&((f=google.getLEI(f))?c+="&lei="+f:k!=google.kEI&&(
c+="&lei="+google.kEI))}a=e||"/"+(l||"gen_204")+"?atyp=i&ct="+a+"&cad="+b+c+m+"&zx="+google.time();/^
http:/i.test(a)&&google.https()?(google.ml(Error("a"),!1,{src:a,glmm:1}),delete h[g]):(window.google&&window.google.vel&&
```

Comment: It seems checkip.amazonaws.com has only ipv4 interface, so it accepts connections only from ipv4 addresses. You could check https://wtfismyip.com/text also. It should recognize v6 and v4 also.

Comment: I tried "https://wtfismyip.com/text" and at first I got this big security exception and then I got an address that was the same as the IPV4 address that "checkip.amazonaws.com" gave me. See updated code to be posted at bottom of question.

Comment: Could you make the code work with https://wtfismyip.com/text ?

Comment: Since IPv6 is supposed to not be using any NAT, you could just get a list of IPv6 addresses assigned to the host instead of asking an external service.

Comment: Make that an answer and if it works I'll give your best answer.

Comment: @SachaTRed Just stumbled across your comment, which I for some reason didn't get around to respond to when you first posted it. The reason I didn't write it as an answer was that I don't know how to do it in Java code. (I am mainly writing C and python code.)

Comment: https://myip.addr.space/help

Comment: You could also try https://icanhazip.com it just returns the ip address in the body so no parsing needed, and it will provide IPv6 when available otherwise IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

My planned solution is to use the instructions in:

http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-fix-certificate-problem-in-HTTPS.html

To get the contents of the https web page https://wtfismyip.com/ (or some other HTTPS page on that site - it doesn't let me get anything if I use http). Then use those contents to deduce your ipv4 and ipv6 addresses. Will see if it works.

Update: This solution works for getting your IPV6 address from an HTTPS site using java